# $X$ is a r.v , $E[X]=1, P(X\geq -1)=1, P(X\geq 0)\geq \frac{9}{10}$ Prove $P(X\geq 10)<\frac{1}{9}$

Tags: probability

$X$ is a r.v , $E[X]=1, P(X\geq -1)=1, P(X\geq 0)\geq \frac{9}{10}$

Prove $P(X\geq 10)<\frac{1}{9}$

$P(X\geq -1)=1, P(X\geq 0)\geq \frac{9}{10} \implies P(-1\leq X<0)\leq\frac{1}{10}$

I think I have to use the Markov equation but I don't know how to use it since $X$ is not completely positive.

I want to subtract the expected value of the negative numbers from E[X] and the use Markov equation
but I don't know how to find the expected value of the negative numbers.

Please help

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[X]\geq -1\cdot P(-1\leq X<0) + 0 \cdot P(0\leq X < 10) + 10 \cdot P(x\geq 10)$$

$$P(-1\leq X<0)=P(-1\leq X)-P(0\leq X)\leq \frac{1}{10}\Rightarrow -1\cdot P(-1\leq X<0) \geq -\frac{1}{10}$$

$$E[X]\geq -\frac{1}{10} + 10 \cdot P(x\geq 10)$$

$$1 \geq -\frac{1}{10} + 10 \cdot P(x\geq 10)$$

$$P(x\geq 10)\leq \frac{11}{100} < \frac{1}{9}$$